# How to use python packages in aws-glue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, aws-glue

I am trying to use python "requests" package in aws-glue. I tried with making .egg file for that package and it won't work. Also tried the making zip of request package and added to the glue job.

How can I execute below lines of code in **AWS-glue**?

```
import requests
print ("Hello")
```

Comment: Did you checked this https://medium.com/slido-dev-blog/aws-glue-python-shell-jobs-first-impressions-d26582123829

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html

Comment: @VishwasNahar I tried the same,

Comment: As of today, this seems to work in AWS Glue Python3 scripts. I believe `requests` had been added recently, but wasn't able to verify with any official source.

Answer (score 0):

Is it spark or python shell job? Answer depends on it.

For python shell job:

Use similar to following line in your setup.py file:

```
install_requires=['requests==2.22.0']
```

Replace `requests` with any library you wish to install.

Comment: It's python shell job.I wan't to access multiple python packages into python shell job.